# How to insert and update date in SQL server 2012 using list view in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I am writing my program using SQL and c#. How can I insert a value of date through a datetimepicker in list view from c# to database? What data type should I use in date in SQL database?

First, I would like to insert the date using datetimepicker. Then, how would it be saved in SQL database in the ReservedDate field? (What line of code should I use). Also what data type should I set the ReservedDate field?

I used this line of code:

```
    command = new SqlCommand("Insert into reservation (date_reservation) 
Values( '" + dateTimePicker4 + "')", MySqlConnection);
```

But an error occured saying:

```
    Additional information: Conversion failed when converting character 
string to smalldatetime data type.
```

What shall I do? Please help me.

Comment: what is the data you are trying to store? is it just the date or date with the time? what is your table definition?

Comment: i am trying to store date only. My table contains the field date_reservation which is in smalldatetime data type.

Comment: i would think that you would need the date in the following format YYYY-MM-DD in c# it is Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: try `dateTimePicker4.Value`

Comment: is it bootstrap date time picker?

Comment: dateTimePicker4.Value worked. thank you so much.

what do you mean by bootstrap date time picker?

Comment: also, how can I store date only? because the one that i am coding is storing date and time.

Comment: i was just wondering if it is this http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ example 4 is called dateTimePicker4 is all and was wondering if you had left out some of the date formatting code, not to worry glad you found an answer

Comment: @Adween, sorry, but I do not use bootstrap datetimepicker, i am using c#

Answer (score 3):

first of all if you are using raw SQL statements you are exposed to SQL injection . Use command object

```
var cmd = "INSERT INTO reservation VALUES (@dateTimePicker )";
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmd, cnn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateTimePicker",dateTimePicker4.Value);
        cnn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"Insert into reservation (date_reservation) Values( '" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "')";
```

Use SQL datetime column type to store this information

Comment: thank you. it worked. let me also ask, how can I store date only?

Comment: @user3156375: dear you can use -> `dateTimePicker1.Value.Date` to get only date part

Comment: If this answer helped you please accept it to close the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
"Insert into Z(...) Values('"+datePicker1.Value.ToString("YYYY/MM/DD")+"')"
```

or

```
"Insert into Z(...) Values('"+datePicker1.Value.Date+"')"
```